# Displaying string variable in editable portion of ComboBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows

I have some value in variable  `string var="some text";`
i have bind the combobox with list but during loadoing of  form i want `var` to be displayed 
in editable portion of Combobox...
Thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 0):

if `var` is part of your list then: `yourcombobox.SelectedText=var`
if not: `yourcombobox.Text=var`